# Error: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices, class file not found

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml

I run:

```
mvn clean test
```

and I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) on project suman: Compilation failure [ERROR]
>   /home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/sce-test/suman/src/test/java/suman/SeleniumTest.java:[21,15]
>   cannot access org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices [ERROR] class file
>   for org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices not found

I am looking at this:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices.html

Looks like my FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver is causing the issue.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>suman</groupId>
  <artifactId>suman</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>suman</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.29.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.21.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.0rc3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.0rc3</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have two test scripts, one uses ChromeDriver, the other uses FirefoxDriver, they look like so:

```
package suman;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {

    private static FirefoxDriver driver;
    private WebElement element;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void openBrowser(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void valid_UserCredential(){

        System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser_3");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        try{
            element = driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a"));
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(element);
        System.out.println("Ending test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    }


    @Test
    public void inValid_UserCredential()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        try{
            element = driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a"));
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(element);
        System.out.println("Ending test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeBrowser(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because dependencies in your pom.xml are not compatible.
Dependency list should be like this.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Or, more generally, a set of the same version.

Comment: any chance that mvn can handle that for me? `mvn install x y z --version=2.4.4` or whatever?